# jquery get row that is being dragged/sortabled between tables

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable, drag

I have 2 tables and when I drag/sort one of rows to another table I need to get the tr dragged, to apply for instance some css style (in my case is to apply top row border using the class .newclass) or to get cells values, but I don't know how can I get the tr (the entire row) that is being dragged using jquery code. In my code I'm trying using the helper function to get the tr but so far with no success.

I have jsfiddle demo to show my code so far and for better understand my pb.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cafc/75LxrwLw/10/)

my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{


    $("tbody.connectedSortable").sortable({
            helper: 'original',
            revert: 'invalid',

             connectWith: ".connectedSortable" //,
         //helper: function() {

        //$('.connectedSortable').addClass('newclass'); // to put the top border on the fly, but doesn't works

                  //return $('<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>')

             //return  $("tbody#x").find("tr:gt(0)").text(); //it doesn't work!! How can I get the tr dragged??

            //}


        });

     $("tbody.connectedSortable").disableSelection();

     $( "#T2" ).droppable({
      accept: ".connectedSortable tr",

      drop: function( event, ui ) {

        return false;
      }

    });



});
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks on advance,
Cafc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the dropped element using `ui.helper` in the `drop` event and set the class to each children td elements.

Code:

```
$("#T2").droppable({
    accept: ".connectedSortable tr",

    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.helper).find("td").addClass("newclass");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/qtny1uy4/

### UPDATE

You can use `sort` event to manipulate the sorted element during sorting, then reset it in the `stop` event.

Code:

```
$("tbody.connectedSortable").sortable({
    helper: 'original',
    revert: 'invalid',
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    sort: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).find("td").addClass("newclass");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).find("td").removeClass("newclass");
    }        
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/qtny1uy4/1/

Comment: thanks for your reply. but I need to change the dragged row and not when it is dropped. So it has to be on sortable side and on the helper event. When I'm starting to drag the row I need immediately to apply the css style, and not when the dropped is done, do u understand what I mean a?? thx

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery UI option callbacks the second argument of callback `ui` is a big object with lots of data available pertaining to the whole widget and event instances.

It is always worth logging this object to console to see what it contains within various event callbacks.

For droppable if you want the draggable that was dropped you can access it as follows:

```
drop:function(evt,ui){

  var elementDropped = ui.draggable;
  alert('First item in the dropped row is ' + elementDropped .children(':first').text());
  console.log(ui); /* <=== have a good look at what's here*/

}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/75LxrwLw/11/)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for your reply. but I need to change the dragged row and not when it is dropped. So it has to be on sortable side and on the helper event. When I'm starting to drag the row I need immediately to apply the css style, and not when the dropped is done, do u understand what I mean a?? thx

Comment: OK, so my answer explains how to look for what you need, you just need an earler event...the principles are the same. Go through the API options and find the event you need. They are all very well docuemnted